# Creating a pandas dataframe from a 2d numpy array (to be a column of 1d numpy arrays) and a 1d np array of labels

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

For example I have these numpy arrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# points could be in n dimension, i need a solution that would cover that up
# and being able to calculate distance between points so flattening the data
# is not my goal.
points = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 1], [100, 100], [-2, -1], [0, 0], [-1, -2]])  # a 2d numpy array containing points in space
labels = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])  # the labels of the points (not necessarily only 0 and 1)
```

I tried to make a dictionary and from that to create the pandas datafram:

```
my_dict = {'point': points, 'label': labels}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, columns=['point', 'label'])
```

But it didn't work and I got the following exception:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Probably it's because of the numpy array of points (a 2d numpy array).

The desired result:

```
        point  label
0      [1, 2]      0
1      [2, 1]      1
2  [100, 100]      1
3    [-2, -1]      0
4      [0, 0]      0
5    [-1, -2]      1
```

Thanks in advance for all the helpers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always try to normalize your data such that each column only contains singular values, not data with a dimension.

In this case, I would do something like this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': points[:,0], 'y': points[:, 1], 'label': labels},
                      columns=['x', 'y', 'label'])
>>> df
     x    y  label
0    1    2      0
1    2    1      1
2  100  100      1
3   -2   -1      1
4    0    0      0
5   -1   -2      0
```

If you truly insist with keeping points as such, transform them to a list of lists or list of tuples before passing to `pandas` to avoid this error.

Comment: Converting them to lists did work Thank you! I can't believe I didn't figure this out, I didn't do the first option you suggested because I need the points in that format it's easier to calculate distances from an outer point using apply and np.norm. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @Niv That (and `apply`) means you're not getting the speed benefits from `pandas`/`numpy`. That's why it's not suggested. Consider this: `dists = np.hypot(df['x'] - refx, df['y'] - refy)` for some reference point `(refx, refy)`.

Comment: It's a bit problematic because the points I get will be of a higher dimension